# Setting default values for inherited properties on a custom control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to subclass a charting tool that has on it an XAxis property, which is of type IAxis (so you can give it a NumericAxis, DateAxis, etc).  When using the base chart normally, I can set the XAxis like so:

```
<chart:BaseChart>
   <chart:BaseChart.XAxis>
      <chart:NumericAxis VisibleRange="{Binding XAxisVisibleRange}" AxisAlignment="Bottom"/>
   </chart:BaseChart.XAxis>
</chart:BaseChart>
```

However I'm not really sure what the best practice is for setting this default axis in a custom control, should it be in the XAML, in the C# code-behind, etc?  I can get it working from the code-behind by setting the XAxis property/bindings in the constructor of my subclass.  This works, I just don't know if it's the "correct" way to do it.

Being new to WPF, I don't know where/how to do it in XAML for the custom control, if that's even the right place for it to be.  Should it go in the control template, the style, somewhere else?  I tried doing a Setter in the style, that did not work (it compiled but I did not see any axes).  From the control template, it doesn't recognize `<chart:BaseChart.XAxis>`.  There are AxisAreas defined for top bottom right and left, and if I simply put the `<chart:NumericAxis etc/>` inside one of those then the axis does show up there, however that doesn't feel correct since it's not actually setting the XAxis property on the BaseChart, plus it's bypassing the AxisAlignment property on the NumericAxis object and explicitly placing the axis in whichever AxisArea I put the axis code in.

Like I said, I do have this working from the code-behind, I just want to make sure I'm doing it the best way I can.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you creating a `CustomControl` or a `UserControl`? The answer depends on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) page on MSDN for a complete answer to your question.

However, in short, for a `CustomControl`, you should create a folder in your application root directory named `Themes`. You should add a XAML file named `Generic.xaml` into this folder and you should put a `ControlTemplate` for your `CustomControl` in there.

For a `UserControl`, you can just add your `Style`s into the `UserControl.Resources` section of the page.

Comment: I've already done that, I just don't know where I should be putting the definition of my axis in the ControlTemplate that I have defined in Generic.xaml...

Comment: Ah, I see... can you find the default `ControlTemplate`? That should show you where it goes.